# How to specify number of elements of each group base in the user input?

Tags: java, arrays

The user will input 2 numbers separated by spaces; the first number determined how many groups the user will input and the second number is how many integers will search for the whole groups. For example input: 3 4.

Because the user input number 3 means there are three groups, now the user will add another 3 numbers for the number of elements he wants to add from each group
How will the user input numbers base on the first input number of the user?
for example, the user inputs 3 as the first number(count of groups), then the user will input 5 7 3 that indicates every number of elements inside each group.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Input:");
    String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    int[] change = new int[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        change[i] = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
    }

    String[] input1 = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    int[] numelement;
    int[] change1 = new int[numelement[0]];
    for(int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++){
        change1[i] = Integer.parseInt(input1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user enters `n` as the number of groups then use a loop to ask the user `n` times to enter `m` elements for each group. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Do you need to create a _jagged_ array of integers representing the groups?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution (shows error if the number of input elements in group is more than the number of groups)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input: ");
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] input = line.split(" ");
    if (input.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("<group-count> <element-count-in-each-group> expected, got " + line);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    int groupCnt = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
    int elementCntInGroups = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);

    int cnt = 0;
    int[][] numbers = new int[groupCnt][elementCntInGroups];
    while (cnt < elementCntInGroups) {
        System.out.print("Input " + groupCnt + " numbers of " + (cnt + 1) + "/" + elementCntInGroups + " row: ");
        input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        if (input.length != groupCnt) {
            System.out.println("Expected " + groupCnt + " numbers separated by space, try again");
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < groupCnt; j++) {
                numbers[j][cnt] = Integer.parseInt(input[j]);
            }
            cnt++;
        }
    }

    // printing
    System.out.println("Numbers in groups: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < groupCnt; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < elementCntInGroups; j++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Result

```
Input: 3 4
Input 3 numbers of 1/4 row: 1 2 3
Input 3 numbers of 2/4 row: 4 5 6
Input 3 numbers of 3/4 row: 7 8 9
Input 3 numbers of 4/4 row: 10 11 12 13
Expected 3 numbers separated by space, try again
Input 3 numbers of 4/4 row: 10 11 12
Numbers in groups: 
1 4 7 10 
2 5 8 11 
3 6 9 12
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that a jagged array of integers `groups` needs to be created (and filled) in this task and the first steps are to get the number of "rows" and then the number of "columns" in each row.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Input the number of groups:");
    int groupCount = sc.nextInt();
    int otherNum = sc.nextInt();
    
    int[][] groups = new int[groupCount][];
    
    System.out.println("Input the number of elements in group:");
    for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        groups[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (int[] group : groups) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(group));
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
Input the number of groups:
3 4
Input the number of elements in group:
5 7 3
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: please help me to show error if the number of input elements in group is more than the number of groups